# Firebase retrieve data from realtime database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3

in my ionic app i am using firebase to retrieve all registered drivers and their data. my schema looks like this;

```
ehara
    Driver
        fjk59KJjkfkjflhghk
            driverId: 1
            location
                 0: 9.086333699999999
                 1: 7.459455999999999
```

my question is this; how can i query the database to get the location of a driver if i know his driverId alone?

Comment: Try `this.afs.collection('Driver', ref => ref.where('driverId', '==', _id))`; and also use google cause this is pretty basic.

Comment: @Swoox: My feeling is that OP uses the Realtime Database, for which I wrote the equivalent query (and better approach) below.

Comment: Well if that is true he better switch while he can.

Comment: Thanks guys and yes i use Realtime Database, and it is a requirement for the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to perform a query to find the drivers with the given ID:

```
firebase.database().ref('Driver')
  .orderByChid('driverId')
  .equalTo('1')
  .once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(driverSnapshot) {
      console.log(driverSnapshot.val());
    });
  })
```

A query can match multiple child nodes, so the code needs to use `snapshot.forEach` over the potentially multiple results.

Since it sounds like ID is already unique in your case, consider using that ID as the key in your `Driver` node.

```
Driver
    id1
        location
             0: 9.086333699999999
             1: 7.459455999999999
```

In that case the read becomes a simple lookup (instead of a query):

```
firebase.database().ref('Driver')
  .child('id1')
  .once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  })
```

Since there can be only one node with a given key in this structure, we also don't need the `forEach` loop anymore.